# Dynamic Mapping one table row to other table column

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

> How to dynamic map one table row to other table columns in c#.

let me explain my question:

I have one table called questions. There are multiple question define in question table. I have display those question in (cshtml) view with the option yes and no. On the other side I have another table with column of those question to store users ans of the question. How can i map those rows to column.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: And what are your table structure?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good database design. Everytime a new question (read, new record) would be added to your "questions" table, you would need to add corresponding column in the "user_responses" table (let's call it that, for now).

Instead, you may change the "user_responses" table to store data as -

```
UserID  QuestionID  Response
A       1           Yes  
A       2           No
B       1           Yes
B       2           Yes
```

This way, if you need to add, say, five more questions to your "questions" table, you would just be required to add five records in that table and not alter the structure of the other (responses) table.